# sshd error shows double slash in authorized_keys path

Tags: ssh, sshd

My server has an ssh user that works (so sshd works).

When I added another user `bob`, then tried to connect, the client shows:

```
bob@1.2.3.4: Permission denied (publickey).
```

And the server's logs show:

```
sshd: Could not open user 'bob' authorized keys '/home/bob//.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
```

That double slash is probably the issue. Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it shows that there is an issue with the path to the authorized_keys file!
usually it's related to the permissions of `.ssh` directory or the user's home directory.

the `.ssh` directory should have permissions of `700` and the `authorized_keys` file should have permissions of `600`

so check them first :

```
ls -ld /home/bob/
ls -ld /home/bob/.ssh/
ls -l /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

to fix that you can easily do like this :

```
chmod 700 /home/bob/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

if the permissions are correct,restart `ssh` service and test it again

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

also check the `authorized_keys` must be in this path :

```
/home/bob/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

good luck !

Answer (score 1):

`$ cat /etc/passwd | grep bob`:

```
bob:.......:/home/bob/:/bin/bash
```

So I did:

```
sudo usermod --home /home/bob bob
```

`$ cat /etc/passwd | grep bob`:

```
bob:.......:/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

**NOTE:**
Linux ignores double slashes in paths, so although this "fixed" the log error on the server, the underlying issue remained. To fix that, see the accepted answer.

Comment: thnx but your answer was this not mine ! (1++)

Comment: @Freeman No what happened was the log entry simply changed from one error to another. But the problem remained, so you were correct, it's a permissions problem! Thank you.

Comment: I'm tempted to delete this answer, but the double slash might send some people down a wild goose chase like it did me, so I'm leaving it here: don't worry about the double slash, as linux ignores them.